# Using sqlite3 to track unit test results

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlite

I have my own unit testing suite based on the unittest library. I would like to track the history of each test case being run. I would also like to identify after each run tests which flipped from PASS to FAIL or vice versa.
I have very little knowledge about databases, but it seems that I could utilize sqlite3 for this task.
Are there any existing solutions which integrate unittest and a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, yes. The only thing that you need is some kind of scripting language or shell script that can talk to sqlite.

You should think of a database like a file in a file system where you don't have to care about the file format. You just say, here are tables of data, with columns. And each row of that is one record. Much like in a Excel table.

So if you are familiar with shell scripts or calling command line tools, you can install sqlite and use the `sqlite`command to interact with the database.

Although I think the first thing you should do is to learn basic SQL. There are a lot of SQL tutorials out there.